# How to change this method so that it doesn't include inner assignments?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I need to change this method so that checkstyle will stop complaining at me.

The inner assignment error is in the for each loop. I want the same functionality but without the error. Thanks!

```
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            //CODE
        }
```

Comment: Side note: There is no `for-each` loop here

Comment: Sorry, meant for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkstyle doesn't like assignments inside other statements. You could change your `for` loop as follows:

```
for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
    // rest of your code
}
```